# Fallback fonts in gedit or geany for Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, language, gedit, geany

On Linux I often use gedit and Geany, and love the interface of both. On Windows (8) however, non seem to support font fallback; that is, when I open a text file containing Chinese and Japanese characters, it displays boxes.

This is not an encoding problem, since changing the editor font to a specifically Chinese one fixes Chinese characters, but not Japanese ones, and I don't have any Chinese or Japanese font with fixed-width latin characters anyway...

How can I tell gedit or geany which fonts to use when the currently selected font misses some characters?

Comment: You might try to use one of the fonts listed here instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font

Comment: Ideally I'd like to stick with my current programming font for Latin characters; it's only for CJK characters that I'm interested in specifying another font.